# ICal attachment time changes

Tags: icalendar

I am sending emails with an ICal attachment because they are an appointment booking for a customer. Here is an example of one sent today.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:MAILTO:email@gmail.com
DTEND:20200722T170000
DTSTAMP:20200720T193038Z
DTSTART:20200722T163000
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:TENTATIVE
SUMMARY:Scissor Cut with Michelle
UID:7978354
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

However, when the customer opens this on his phone in GMail it displays as

[image: Customers image]

My best guess is that his phone is doing zome kind of Time Zone adjustment, but I haven't defined any time zones.

Comment: That is interesting.  Strictly speaking those are local or floating datetimes and should always be what they are no matter the timezone.  IE: 1630 everywhere in any timezone.  Maybe you could workaround it by specifying a timezone? or using ETC time?

Comment: Maybe the client has different devices with different timezones?  Gmail may then be 'picking' one and trying to be consistent across the clients devices.  See https://support.google.com/mail/thread/3825759?hl=en

Comment: Also https://support.schedulista.com/en/articles/365815-why-is-my-client-s-email-in-gmail-showing-the-wrong-timezone

Comment: Try using Form#2 (UTC time) or with tz reference Form#3 https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-3-5-date-time.html

Comment: It is interesting because I deliberately didn't add time zones in the ICal to try and stop it doing adjustments, but still is.

Comment: As the links say it may arise because the clients may have multiple devices that are in different timezones AND you are using a floating or local DATETIME.   If you used UTC or Timezone, then EVEN if the clients have different devices in different timezones, it would not matter because the time would be much more clearly defined.